# Stone foundation gap

Tags: foundation

Is it normal for a house to not sit flush on a stone foundation? Every other part of the house seems to align with the stones. No massive interior cracks to indicate foundation damage though. [image]

Comment: Are you referring to what appears to be a gap that several small critters could climb through, or do you mean that the wall is not flush to the outside of the wall? You seem to be asking two different questions and I'm not sure which one you're after...

Comment: Unless the stones are cut or have a flat concrete/mortar  top, gaps are possible.  If a section seems to have a bigger gap, possible it was not finished as well or has sunken a bit.